# Why my digital ocean droplets stops working suddenly?

Tags: devops, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

My web application hosted on a digital ocean droplets stops working suddenly. What can it be?

Comment: But when I restart it works again. But after some time it goes offline again.

Comment: Are there any logs you can peek into? Syslogs? Or something?